# Unknown HTML tag search: <spinner> -- what is it and where does it come from?

Tags: html, angular

**EDIT: By process of elimination, seems to be part of the https://github.com/mpalourdio/ng-http-loader module which is added by some other dependency. Interestingly enough, at first glance that module uses `<ng-http-loader>` as tag, not `<spinner>`.**

In an "inherited" Angular 6 application, I have this line in my app.component.html:

`<spinner></spinner>`

This seems to be used to generate an animated overlay while loading data (squares appear and disappear in a wave from lower left to upper right corner):
[image]

The question is: what tag is this?

If I disable it, the loading animation is not shown anymore. But I cannot find anywhere in the code or on the internet something related to it, or an element that would refer to it. So I can't find out who controls its behaviour.

My app.component.ts:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';    
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';    
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { BreadcrumbService, BreadcrumbComponent } from 'ng5-breadcrumb' ;   


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  env = environment;

  constructor(..., private sw: SwUpdateService, public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sw.checkForUpdates();
    this.sw.onUpdateAvailable().subscribe((updEvent) => {
      this.snackBar.open('Software update available!', 'Update').onAction().subscribe(() => {
        document.location.reload();
      });
    });
  }

  navigateA(): void {
    this.router.navigate(["/a"]);
  }

  navigateB(): void {
    this.router.navigate(["/b"]);
  }

  navigateC():  void {
    this.router.navigate(["/c"]);
  }

  navigateD(): void {
    this.router.navigate(["/d"]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This tag comes from the component used to show this kind of loading animation, maybe an external module in your app.module.ts like NgxSpinner.

Comment: Thanks! Well, this much was clear ;-) I just thought I'd ask on the off-chance that someone recognizes it, before I go through all the dependencies manually.

Comment: PS. I don't have any Angular spinner component in my dependencies, so I assume some other dependency adds it.